# Making a request with Amazon using Rest Sharp in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I'm trying to make a request towards the amazon's API via method called search item by UPC. So far what I've did here is following:

```
   var client = new RestClient("http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml");
    string itemid = "694318020913";
    var timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
     var signature = getSignatureKey("some key here", timestamp, "east-us-1", "iam");
     var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
     request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Large&SearchIndex=All&IdType=UPC&ItemId="+itemid+"&AWSAccessKeyId=accesssKey&AssociateTag=associateTag&Timestamp=" + timestamp + "&Signature=" + signature, ParameterType.RequestBody);
     var res = client.Execute(request).Content;
```

And these are the helper methods that I've found at Amazon's documentation that are supposed to calculate the signature:

```
  static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key)
        {
            string algorithm = "HmacSHA256";
            KeyedHashAlgorithm kha = KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create(algorithm);
            kha.Key = key;

            return kha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
        }

        static byte[] getSignatureKey(string key, string dateStamp, string regionName, string serviceName)
        {
            byte[] kSecret = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(("AWS4" + key).ToCharArray());
            byte[] kDate = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
            byte[] kRegion = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
            byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
            byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);

            return kSigning;
        }
```

Now what confuses me here is that I'm getting the following message from amazon:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details c# .net
```

My questions are:

1. In this getSignatureKey method, which key do I actually have to pass?

   - I have several keys from amazon and they are:
   - access key, secret key, associate key ?

What am I doing wrong here? Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Anyone guys? I suspect this might be the problem with signature type itself , the method returns byte[] which I then simply convert to string... ? Somehow I feel this isn't the right way to do it ?

Comment: "which key do I actually have to pass?"  secret key

Comment: @User987 do you already found a solution? I'm stuck at the same problem.

Comment: Did someone ever found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for these 3 years of pain, but for future readers:

Change this line:

`var signature = getSignatureKey;`

To :

```
var signatureKey = getSignatureKey;
```

Now you realize that we sign with signatureKey, not with the original key.

Remove "`&Signature=' + signature`" and use signatureKey to sign the string that is being added as a request parameter (url encode the names and values first, leaving = and & un-encoded). - Timestamp is probably the only part that needs url encoding.  Then url encode the signed string that you just created and add it to the end of the original un-signed string.  Now add the new string to the request with AddParameter.

If you get the "does not match" error again, eliminate RestSharp as a possible problem by replacing it with your own code that uses System.Net.HttpWebRequest. Figuring out how to use HttpWebRequest will not make this task that much more difficult.